# Cannot validate my form using jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a form using jQuery, but it does not work at all and I don't receive the error. I suspect if the version of the jQuery validate is compatible with the jQuery version that I am using. I don't receive any error message related to validation. As a test example I wanted to validate the customerName and make that to be required. If I left the field blank and press the payment button, the button fires and I get no messages stating that the field is required. In my javascript I initially hided the form until some conditions get valid.

HTML snippet in head tag

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

My form

```
<form action="/localDeliveryPayment" method="get" id="localDeliveryCheckoutForm">
        <p><label for="customerName">Name:</label> <input type="text" name="customerName" maxlength="20" required id="customerName"></p>
<p><label for="customerEmail">Email:</label> <input type="email" name="customerEmail" maxlength="50" required id="customerEmail"></p>
<p><label for="customerMobile">Mobile:</label> <input type="text" name="customerMobile" maxlength="10" required id="customerMobile"></p>
<p><label for="comments">Comments:</label> <textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="300" id="comments">
</textarea></p>
<p><label for="deliveryTime">Deliverytime:</label> <select name="deliveryTime" id="deliveryTime">
  <option value="15:00">15:00</option>

  <option value="15:15">15:15</option>

</select></p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="paymentButton">Payment</button>
    </form>
```

My javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function(){ 
    //hide all elements
    document.getElementById("localDeliveryForm").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("takeawayPickUp").style.display = "none"; 
    $("#localDeliveryCheckoutForm").validate({
        //specifying rules for the validation
        rules: {
            customerName: {required : true},     
        },
        messages: {
            customerName: {required : "Please enter your name"},
        },
        
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Where is your submit button ? Also , your payment button has `type="button"` so it will not trigger form submit event .

Comment: sorry for the confusion. It is the payment button. I will edit my question in my post to make this clear.

Comment: Its working just [fine](https://jsfiddle.net/w7bfn2pg/) . I have just change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are absolutely right. Thanks a lot I am not aware that it wouldn't work if the button type is "button". The button is linked to the javascript onclick, and therefore I didn't bother with type="submit" as upon clicking I will submit to the backend after doing some validation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Swati changing the button type to submit fixed the problem

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="paymentButton">Payment</button>
```

Thanks a lot!